# 1 Volt reading between hot phase of sub panel and enclosure and frame

Tags: grounding, subpanel

My grounding bus in my subpanel, which is secured to the panel frame, reads 122 VAC to hot phase which is great.  I also get 122 VAC from hot phase to neutral bus.  Shouldn't I also get 122 VAC +/- from hot phase to the cabinet being that it is bonded to the grounding bus?  Instead I get a reading of 1 volt.

Comment: Make sure you're on to metal and not on paint.

Comment: Panels are usually painted well.  Paint is an insulator.   Did you touch bare(non-painted) metal of the panel?

Comment: I installed a brand new panel, passed inspection, etc. so no paint,
On a lark, ck’d that panel frame was bonded and seems like it’s not.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean by painted--not a coat over the new metal.  Will recheck on the bare metal.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to read voltages through the paint on the panel. Try taking the reading from a metal connector screwed into a knockout on the panel and to hot. If you don't get a good reading, then your ground bus isn't connected electrically to the panel.